# What is the step by step explanation for pandas style highlighting format?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, styles

This is a very newbie question, but most tutorials are assuming students understand this, but I'm not. I found this example of pandas formatting style:

```
def highlight_max(s):
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: green' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

This function paints the cell containing the highest value in the column. I didn't understand what this is doing. I know is a broad question, but I really wanted to understand the steps in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the following random dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

[image]

Now, let take a look at this function you have

```
def highlight_max(s):
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: green' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

so, basically, this function takes each column and mark the largest value of each column. Let's apply it on your dataframe and see the output:

```
df.apply(highlight_max)
```

[image]

as you can see, we have another dataframe with the same size as `df`. All values are empty string except the max value in each column has as string `'background-color: green'`.

Now we apply this new dataframe on the original dataframe but with styling function.

```
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

[image]

That's it. Each cell with no style is the same as before and each cell with `'background-color: green'` is green.

Comment: avoid using pictures as much as possible, paste the result as `code`

Comment: thanks, I have the code for each line, but I don't know how to show the output of jupyter as html here.

Comment: @reza I think you can do `df.style.apply(highlight_max).render()` to get the HTML, but in this case the image is far clearer. The HTML would probably be more confusing.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it tried it, but html it doesn't come with the required styles and it shows up a simple table

Comment: Try `print(df.style.apply(highlight_max).render())`? Or just run this in a python terminal instead of jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

That snippet comes directly out of the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), however you have left off an essential part which is how the function is called:

```
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

this is using the `.style.apply` function, which if you didn't understand that first doc page should lead you to look up the documentation for [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html). These docs tell us:

> Apply a function column-wise, row-wise, or table-wise.
>
> Updates the HTML representation with the result.

It also says this about the function you are pass to it (the bold parts are my comments):

> `func` **(i.e. your `highlight_max`)** should take a `Series` or `DataFrame` (depending on `axis`), and return an object with the same shape.

ok so now let's look at your function, I've added in type hints to make it clearer

```py
def highlight_max(s: pd.Series) -> Sequence[str]:
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: green' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

So this function accepts a pandas series and outputs a list of strings that is the same size of that series. It is going contain strings of CSS styling that should be applied to the HTML that is used to display your pandas table. In particular, your function is going to set the [background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) property to be green.

Let's say you table has 2 columns and 3 rows. For each column, this function needs to output a list like this:

```py
[
    "",
    "background-color: green",
    "",
]
```

if you wanted the 2nd row of that column to be green.

But you don't want this for the second row, you want it for any rows that contain the maximum value of that column. So how do you find that? One way is to make a boolean series

```py
is_max = s == s.max()
```

which will make a series (I'm just going to write it as a list) like this (assuming the max was on the second row)

```py
[
    False,
    True,
    False,
]
```

so that takes care of `is_max`.

The next line just converts that boolean series to the list with the CSS. It's using a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension, if you don't know what that is stop what you are doing and take an online python basics course before continuing.

But let's write it out as a for loop:

```py
css = []
for v in is_max:
    if v:  # same as if v is True
        css.append("background-color: green")
    else:
        css.append("")
return css
```

btw I find it odd that the pandas docs decided to use a loop for this when  I assume you could use pandas' vectorization:

```
is_max = s == s.max()
css = s.copy()
css[is_max] = "background-color: green"
css[~is_max] = ""
```